# Detecting image/text or just an img or text in message.content

Tags: node.js, discord.js

What is a better way of detecting if a message contains an `image` and `text` or just `text` or just an `image`, as I would like to be able to output either both or one or the other for this embed.

```js
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`${this.client.user.username} Global Chat`)
    .addField(`${badge}`, '\u200b', true)
    .addField(`\`${message.author.username}\` said:`, `${trim(message.content, 1000)}`, true)
    .setFooter(`This message was sent from the guild: ${results.guildName}`)

if (message.attachments.size > 0) {
    if (message.attachments.every(attachIsImage)) {
        embed.setImage(message.attachments.array()[0].url)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the `message.attachments` and `message.content` properties. I don't think there's a better way to do what you're trying to do:

```js
if (message.attachments) {
    embed.setImage(message.attachments.first()); // or use .array()[0]
}

if (message.content) {
    // add the content to the embed
}
```